# why does my quick sort sometimes miss a pair of numbers?

Tags: python, quicksort

ive made my own quick sort algorithm and it works fairly well, expect every 3 or 4 sorts, it misses a pair of numbers and the final list remains to be unsorted.

for example, instead of the list being [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], it'll be [1, 2, 3, **5, 4,** 6]

this is my code

```
  for i in range(len(lista)):
    pivot = random.choice(lista)
    for j in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[j]>pivot and lista.index(lista[j])<lista.index(pivot):
            lista[lista.index(pivot)] = lista[j]
            lista[j] = pivot
        elif lista[j]<pivot and lista.index(lista[j])>lista.index(pivot):
            lista[lista.index(pivot)] = lista[j]
            lista[j] = pivot
        else:
            j = j
```

i dont know what the issue might be, even visualizing the code in [python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/) doesnt help because in the first pivot selection, it always picks the same pivots

help

Comment: This is not quick sort. Where did you get this algorithm from?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the quick sort algorithm requires you to use recursion, to apply the algorithm in each sublist created once you choose a pivot.
In the example that you have you are choosing a pivot randomly for each item of the list, it could sort the list if at the end you have chosen all items at least once (or maybe the majority of them, I am not sure), but since you are choosing them randomly it is probably that sometimes the pivots chosen are not enough to order the list properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).